# How to access a member function to a template file in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, oop, themes

I'm trying to build a WordPress theme with a lot of customizations. I'm trying to build it using the Object-Oriented approach so that I can create functions without worrying about naming them unique and I think it will be easier to bring in updates in the future.

The problem that I'm facing is when I try to access one of the member functions using an object it returns errors.

I tried with creating a global object to access the member function but it throws an error like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function distribute_numbers() on null.
```

### functions.php

```
if( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' )) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * Theme Calculations
 */
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/calc.php';
```

### inc/calc.php

```
class Theme_Calc{
    public function distribute_numbers(){
        $array = [10, 9, 8, 6, 4,2];
        return $array;
    }
}

global $obj_calc;
$obj_calc = new Theme_Calc();
```

### front-page.php

```
</head>
<body>

<?php 

global $obj_calc;

//$nums = Theme_Calc::distribute_numbers();

$nums = $obj_calc->distribute_numbers();

?>
```

This is a simplified version of what I've tried so far and every time when I try to access the member function on a template file, it gives me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function distribute_numbers() on null.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change distribute_numbers to static member function :

```
class Theme_Calc{
    public static function distribute_numbers(){
        $array = [10, 9, 8, 6, 4,2];
        return $array;
    }
}
```

and call it in front-page.php

```
Theme_Calc::distribute_numbers();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. The answer didn't help though. And why is it need to be a static function?

Comment: Using static you can directly call the member function without defining the global variable and function object.  But I have checked your code and it looks great, I am not getting the fatal error. Can you please check the include file path inc/calc.php

Comment: It now gives me a different error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Theme_Calc' not found. I double-checked the file path as you said, it looks fine. Not sure what I'm missing here!

Comment: I'm still instantiating the class using an object like this: global $obj_calc;
$obj_calc = new Theme_Calc();  Is that needs to be changed?

Comment: I think I got it, please call your global function just above wp_footer(); function in front-page.php

Comment: hey, sorry I couldn't check it for a few days. I will do it today, but why I'm wondering why do you think we need to call that in the bottom though?